# MobxStateTree without useState?

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-state-tree

Who can explain to me how to make a model in mobx for exemple

```
const ListsStore = types.model('Lists', {

   lists: types.array(types.model('List', {
   title: '',
   desc: '',

   }))
})
```

now i want call this array in my React component and add new list in lists but also i want save input data for current list in model

for example:

```
const { title, desc } = useRoot.ListsStore

    <input type='text' value={title} />
    <input type='text' value={desc} />
```

now for save value from input i save in useState in component, and after it send to array but i want to save state directly in mobx

how i do it now in component

```
    const { sendToList } = useRoot.ListsStore
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('')
    const [desc, setDesc] = useState('')
    
        <input type='text' value={title} onChange=(event => setTitle(event.target.value)) />
        <input type='text' value={desc}  onChange=(event => setDesc(event.target.value)/>

  <button onClick=(() => sendToList({
    title,
     desc
  }) > 
   Send 
</button>
```

P.S.: sorry for grammatical use translate

Comment: You could use the [useLocalStore](https://mobx-react.js.org/state-local) hook if you prefer to handle your local state with MobX instead of regular `useState` hooks. Or do you mean that you want the input value changes to be stored in your `ListsStore` directly?

Comment: Yes, i want stored directly in listsstore

Answer (score 0):

You could break out your nested `List` model into a separate variable and add `actions` to it for changing the `title` and `desc` and use those actions directly in the React components.

**Example**

```js
const List = types
  .model("List", {
    title: "",
    desc: ""
  })
  .actions((self) => ({
    setTitle(title) {
      self.title = title;
    },
    setDesc(desc) {
      self.desc = desc;
    }
  }));

const ListStore = types.model("Lists", {
  lists: types.array(List)
});

const listStore = ListStore.create({
  lists: [
    { title: "foo", desc: "bar" },
    { title: "baz", desc: "quz" }
  ]
});

export default observer(function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {listStore.lists.map((list, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={list.title}
            onChange={(event) => list.setTitle(event.target.value)}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            value={list.desc}
            onChange={(event) => list.setDesc(event.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
});
```

Comment: ok, but how now use setTitle and setDesc from model ?